# Number of ways to arrange $10$ people on a $40$ seat bench where where each person sits at least $2$ chairs away from the others

Tags: combinatorics

I tried arranging $10$ people in a row, inserting $2$ seats in between each $2$, So far using $28$ seats $(10+18)$. Now we have 12 seats to insert in $11$ 'spots' on the edges and in between each $2$ people.

Getting a total of $10! * 11^{12}$

Comment: the problem with that is that the chairs are not distinct.  If you put the first of the extra $12$ in slot $C$ and the second in slot $F$, that's indistinguishable from putting the first in slot $F$ and the second in slot $C$.  Better to use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.)

Comment: Should say:  your approach is otherwise sound.  You've got $12$ indistinguishable objects which must be placed in $11$ distinguished bins.  It's fine if a bin is left empty.  Perfect set up for Stars and Bars.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have $30$ blue balls and $10$ green balls.  First, we will arrange them so that there are at least two blue balls between each pair of green balls.

Set aside $18$ of the blue balls.  The remaining $22$ balls can be arranged in $\binom{22}{10}$ ways.  Now insert two blue balls to the immediate right of each of the first nine green balls.  Number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls represents the positions of the $10$ people, each of whom will be separated by at least two seats from their nearest neighbors.  Since there are $10!$ ways of arranging the people in the positions designated by the numbers on the green balls, there are
$$\binom{22}{10}10!$$
admissible seating arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

- Form $10$ boxes of $\boxed{person- 2 chairs}$ with the last box only $\boxed{person}$
- $\overbrace{\boxed{PCC}\;\boxed{PCC} ......... \boxed{P}}^{\text {10 boxes}}$
- $22$ entities including excess chairs are there, place the boxes in $\binom{22}{10}$ ways with short box as the last box
- Permute men to finaly get $\binom{22}{10}10!$

Answer (score 0):

Case xxxxxxxP

If the last chair is taken, we have to place the rest of nine PCC'and twelve C's in a row $ 21 \choose 9$

(where PCC is a person with two free chairs to the right, and C stands for a free chair)

Case xxxxxxxPC

If the last person has a free chair toward the end, we have to place nine PCC'c and eleven C's in a row   $ 20 \choose 9 $

Case xxxxxxxPCC

If the last person has two chairs toward the end, it remains nine PCC's and ten chairs to place $ 19 \choose 9 $

Continuing,

$ {21 \choose 9} + {20 \choose 9} + {19 \choose 9} + \cdots = {22 \choose 10}  $

Comment: Yo  correctly counted the number of ways of arranging nine PCCs, one P, and twelve Cs so that there are at least two Cs between each P, but you forgot to arrange the people in the positions occupied by the Ps.

Answer (score 0):

> Number of ways to arrange 10 people on a 40 seat bench where where each person sits at least 2 chairs away from the others

As lulu indicated in the comments, this problem can (somewhat inelegantly) be attacked as a Stars and Bars problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

First, let $A$ denote the number of solutions to:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{11} = (40 - 10) = 30.$
- $x_1, x_{11} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_{10} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$

Then, the desired enumeration will be

$$[(10)!] \times A. \tag1 $$

(1) above is explained as follows:

- Number the seats from left to right, so that seat 1 is the leftmost seat, and seat 40 is the rightmost seat.
- The $10$ positions assigned to the $10$ people create $11$ regions.  One of the regions is before the first person, and each of the other regions is after each person.
- If the region before the first person, which is represented by the variable $~x_1,~$ equals $0$, this corresponds to the first person occupying seat 1.
  Similarly, if the region after the last person, which is represented by the variable $~x_{11},~$ equals $0$, this corresponds to the last person occupying seat 40.
- Since $10$ of the $40$ seats will be occupied, the sum of the gaps (i.e. regions of empty seats) will be $40 - 10 = 30.$
- The constraint that there must be at least $2$ empty chairs between each person will be satisfied, if and only if each of the variables $x_2, \cdots, x_{10}$ is $~\geq 2.$
- Each satisfying solution (i.e. each satisfying set of **ordered values**) $\{x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_{11}\},$ will exactly determine which $(10)$ of the $(40)$ seats are assigned to people. 
  There will then be $[(10)!]$ ways of permuting the $(10)$ people to fill these $(10)$ seats.

---

From basic Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions to:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$

is $~\displaystyle \binom{n + (k-1)}{k-1}.$

The original problem can be converted into the **basic** format by the change of variables:
$y_i = x_i - 2 ~: ~i \in \{2,3,\cdots,10\}.$

So, the value of $A$ may be computed by considering the *equivalent* problem:

- $x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + \cdots + y_{10} + x_{11} = 30 - [9 \times 2] = 12.$
- $x_1, x_{11} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_2, y_3, \cdots, y_{10} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, $~\displaystyle A = \binom{12 + [11 - 1]}{11 - 1} = \binom{22}{10}.$

Therefore, the final computation is

$$[(10)!] \times \binom{22}{10} = \frac{(22)!}{(12)!}.$$